# Erro ao tentar ler arquivo de excel C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel

```
public partial class FrmEditar : Form
{
    private OleDbConnection _olecon;
    private OleDbCommand _oleCmd;
    private static string _arquivo = string.Empty;
    private string _stringConexao = string.Empty;
    private string _consulta;

    public FrmEditar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnSelecionarExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        OpenFileDialog vAbreArq = new OpenFileDialog
        {
            //Filter = "*.xls | Microsoft Excel| *.xlsx | Microsoft Excel",
            Title = Resources.frmEditar_btnSelecionarExcel_Click_Selecione_o_Arquivo,
            RestoreDirectory = true
        };

        if (vAbreArq.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                _arquivo = vAbreArq.FileName;
                _stringConexao = $@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={_arquivo};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;ReadOnly=False';";
                _olecon = new OleDbConnection(_stringConexao);
                _olecon.Open();

                _oleCmd = new OleDbCommand
                {
                    Connection = _olecon,
                    CommandType = CommandType.Text
                };


                txtExcel.Text = vAbreArq.FileName;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }       

    private void btnFechar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }

    private void btnBuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            _oleCmd.CommandText = "SELECT CodFunci, NomeFunci FROM [Empregados$] Where CodFunci = " + txtCodigo.Text;
            OleDbDataReader reader = _oleCmd.ExecuteReader(); \\Erro acontece nessa linha.

            while (reader != null && reader.Read())
            {
                txtCodigo.Text = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
                txtNome.Text = reader.GetString(1);
            }

            reader?.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

O erro que acontece é:

Empregados$ is a not valid name. Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long.

O nome da planilha que estou usando é Empregados.xlsx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Empregados$` deve ser o nome da planilha **dentro** do arquivo e não o nome **do** arquivo, ex:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No arquivo exemplo acima, teria que usar `Planilha1$`

Comment: Que vontade de te dar um beijo mano!! Valeu de mais. Tá bom que foi idiota eu não ter raciocinado isso, mas valeu de mais.

Comment: ao invés do beijo, dá um voto na minha resposta aqui do lado esquerdo. será bem recebido kkkkkk  ;)

Comment: Não me permitiram o voto, mas dei como resposta certa, é tudo que posso fazer rsrsrs